# readbean php как правильно сделать запрос

Tags: php

Всем привет на данном этапе собираюсь с mysql мигрировать на orm readbean  php вот застрял в начале собственно! Соединения с бд есть далее есть форма прохода авторизаций, в бд есть таблица user с логином и паролем ввожу получаю (ошибку 3) и обновляюсь не могу составить запрос чтобы он считал с таблицы user, user_name и password в мануалке запутался... в самом конце файла старое соединение и чтение с бд!

```html
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Work_Log/main.php');
if(!getAuth()){
 if ($_POST['login']=='' or $_POST['password']==''){
  exit ( '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=../../?error=2" />'); 
 }
 $login=getCheck($_POST['login'],'login');
 $password=getCheck($_POST['password'],'password');
 //echo $login;
  //echo $password;
 if($login=='0'){
  exit ('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=../../?error=1" />');
 }   

 require "../../db.php";
 R::exec('select * from user where login="'.$login.'" and password="'.$password.'"');
 if ($row['id_user']==''){
  exit ( '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=../../?error=3" />'); 
 }
 else {
  $_SESSION['id']=$row['id_user'];
  $_SESSION['type']=$row['user_type'];
  $_SESSION['name']=$row['user_name'];
  exit ('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://localhost/Work_Log/page/admin/">'); 
 } 
}
else {
 exit ( '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=../../" />'); 
}
#getConect();
#$query= mysql_query('select * from user where login="'.$login.'" and password="'.$password.'"');
#$row= mysql_fetch_array($query);
//echo $row['id_user'];
?>
```

и да я совсем новичок поэтому подробное объяснения не помешают, благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для запроса и получения одно строки используется `R::getRow`

В Вашем случае нужно заменить `exec` на

```
$row = R::getRow( 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE login=:login AND password=:password', [ ':login'=>$login, ':password'=>$password ] );
```

Comment: Больше будет информации от самой строки

Comment: Ну конечно , я пропустил переменные в кавычки оберните. Поправил выше.

Comment: Я выше поправил еще стрелку, вы не упустили ?

Comment: :)) еще ошибка в спешке таблица user. И не нужно все оборачивать только то что через : Этот запрос проверил на своей базе